# How to prevent drop down menu closing

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I would like to prevent closing the drop-down menu when I clicked. I only want to close the drop-down menu when clicking outside or click the specify button that inside the drop-down menu.

Here is my code =>

```
<div className="loginuser">
            <button type="button"  className="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle p-0 fontsize135 "  id="dropdownMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/74e30e21c1a9aa8822feddd44d7a893c?s=48&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG&amp;f=1" width="24" height="24" className="mr-2" alt="administrator"></img>
              Administrator
            </button>
            <div className="dropdown-menu loginuserdiv"  aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.handleloginuserclose}>Close</button>

            </div>
          </div>
```

When I click the toggle button, I show `loginuserdiv` and I only want to close when clicking outside of the drop-down menu or click the close button inside the drop-down menu.

Now the drop-down menu div is close wherever I click and How to stop this one?

I tried with `e.stopPropagation();` in the drop-down menu div click and it's not working.

Comment: What kind of drop-down menu you are using?

Comment: @PeterAmbruzs, I use bootstrap 4.